# Is it possible to find correlation between variables that have non-numeric values?

Tags: dataframe, correlation

I have a 3 column table, say A,B,C. For every value in A, there are corresponding single-word strings in B and C. These strings belong to a finite set of words (set size 70 for words in B and 30 for C). Every value in A is unique. Is it possible to find a correlation between B and C? For each value in A, Strings in B and C are related according to what I know about the data. But can that be found mathematically?
I understand that correlation cannot be found between non-numeric variables; but is there some way of converting the strings to some form that could help find the correlation between them?

Example (dummy) table:
**A   B   C** 
a   x   r
b   y   t
c   x   s
d   x   r
e   y   t

How to find correlation between B and C?

Comment: maybe converting the letters to ascii could work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but The actual contents as I mentioned are strings and not just single letters.